# Draw a diagonal line across form that redraws when the form is resized

Tags: vb.net, drawing, gdi

I just started with GDI - the first line was ok - but the second....
I want to draw a simple diagonal line from (0,0) to (MaxWidth,MaxHeight).

Here is my code:

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
    Dim stift As New Pen(Brushes.Black, 3)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim x1 = 0, y1 = 0, x2 = Me.Size.Width, y2 = Me.Size.Height
        g.DrawLine(stift, x1, y1, x2, y2)
    End Sub
End Class
```

But the line ends at the MaxWidth and MaxHeight of the first unchanged form.
Anybody any idea?

Comment: Get rid of the CreateGraphics and use the Paint event.  Also, use the ClientSize for the width and the height.

Answer (score 1):

Quick example of drawing the line in the Paint() event, and allowing it to be toggled with a Button:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private x1 As Integer = 0
    Private y1 As Integer = 0
    Private x2 As Integer = 0
    Private y2 As Integer = 0

    Private DrawLine As Boolean = False
    Private stift As New Pen(Brushes.Black, 3)

    Public Sub New()
        InitializeComponent()

        x2 = Me.ClientSize.Width
        y2 = Me.ClientSize.Height
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_SizeChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.SizeChanged
        x2 = Me.ClientSize.Width
        y2 = Me.ClientSize.Height
        Me.Refresh()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles MyBase.Paint
        If DrawLine Then
            Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
            g.DrawLine(stift, x1, y1, x2, y2)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        DrawLine = Not DrawLine
        Me.Refresh()
    End Sub

End Class
```

This approach allows you to change the coords from somewhere else and call Refresh() to update the screen.  For more than one line, consider using a List() that holds information about the coords, then iterate over that in the Paint() event.